# Ошибка Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: php, jquery

Имеется такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    var json;
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(result) {
            json = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            if (json.url) {
                window.location.href = '/' + json.url;
            } else {
                alert(json.status + ' - ' + json.message);
            }
        },
    });
});
});
.......
<form action="/admin/addBanner" method="post">
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
        <p><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Имя"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="sendMessageButton">Отправить</button>
</div>
</form>
```

При нажатии на кнопку на сервере в переменной $_POST ничего нету. Открываю инспектор код в хроме. Там такая ошибка:
*VM732:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] ()
    at Object.success (form.js:13)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at A (jquery.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.js:4)*
В чем здесь проблема? Или подскажите как отладить, куда смотреть

Comment: Добавьте php скрипт, который обрабатывает запрос.

Comment: Тут так просто не скинуть из за класса route https://github.com/php-youtube/php-blog я а основе вот этого проекта делаю. addBanner это у меня функция addBannerAction по аналогии с addAction

Comment: Что помогло? Как решил проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Задайте свойство `contentType: 'application\json'` в js-скрипте.
2. Убедитесь что ваша страница, на которую идет запрос отправляет данные именно в JSON формате. Можно воспользоваться на сервере методом `json_encode()`, если у вас php сервер. Так же можно отправлять данные в виде `XML`, но для этого надо будет поменять параметр `contentType: 'application\xml'`.

Вообще выберите для себя некое правило, или же договоренность, с помощью которой ваш фронт(js+html, не важно) будет общаться с сервером - тут вам помогут заголовки, которые как раз таки и указываются в параметре `contentType`. Наиболее популярный способ отправки\получения данных - JSON, он поддерживается на большинстве платформ.

Comment: проставил contentType не помогло. Добавил такой код в скрипт var formData = new FormData(this)
    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
     console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
    } выводится name, значение которое вбиваю. Что дальше делать не знаю

Comment: Сервер на чем написан?

Comment: У вас ошибку выбрасывает `jQuery.parseJSON()`  - он ждет то что ему придет JSON-массив, но получает он по всей видимости html, или же xml

Comment: Сервер апач из набора денвера

Comment: Я имел ввиду язык серверной части какой :). Но уже по комментариям ниже понял что php

Comment: Я вот чувствую, что я не на ту страницу ссылаюсь через параметр action, но как проверить не знаю

Comment: Вбейте в адресную строку и узнаете)

Comment: Если вбить из параметра action формы, то адрес правильный

Answer (score 0):

У вас возвращается html вместо json.

Comment: как исправить это?

Comment: @helldrg возвращать json вместо html. Смотреть в свой php-код

Comment: в php коде вот <?php if (!empty($_POST)) 
  {
   var_dump($_POST);
  }. В условие не заходит, а должно по идеи

Comment: `var_dump` - она возвращает ответ на фронт, НО не в JSON формате, а js-скрипт ждет JSON

Comment: @Mully Спааасссииббоооо, я просто недавно программирую в этой области, не знал, что если такой код поставить, то не отреагирует воспользовался функцией json_encode и хоть увидел, что заходит в функцию. Скрипт правильно работает, дело в php коде